# 1 dummy coded variable and 4 continuous variables in standard regression

Tags: multiple-regression

I will try to be as specific as possible and I do hope that someone can steer me on the right track.

I have 1 categorical variable for grade consisting of grade 1, 2, 3 and 4 which will be dummy coded. I also have 4 continuous predictor variables. Now, the perplexing part is I would like to know if it is possible to see the changes in strength of predictive power of the continuous variables on the DV between grades? I am told that I can do this in MR. Basically, besides looking at whether these variables predict the DV, my research is also looking at the whether different continuous variables predict or do not predict (or difference in predictive power for) the DV when participants are in grade 1, 2, 3 or 4.

If you need more info, I will be glad to furnish you with more details.

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is with interactions. This consists (in your case) of multiplying the continuous variables by the categorical variable and adding them as moer independent variables. How to do this *exactly* depends on your software, but it is pretty simple in any software.

*Interpretation* of the results can be a little tricky; I recommend looking at lots of graphs; one good set here would be the DV vs. each of the continuous IVs (one plot for each) with one line for each grade.